# iptables ACCEPT rule doesn't work as expected

Tags: iptables

Here is my /etc/sysconfig/iptables configuration:

```
*nat
:PREROUTING ACCEPT [106:8676]
:POSTROUTING ACCEPT [1885:116707]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [1885:116707]
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 162 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1162
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 514 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1514
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 69 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1069
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 161 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1161
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 162 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1162
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 514 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1514
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 69 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1069
-A PREROUTING -p udp -m udp --dport 161 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1161
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 162 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1162
-A OUTPUT -d 127.0.0.1/32 -p udp -m udp --dport 162 -j REDIRECT --to-ports 1162
COMMIT
*filter
:INPUT ACCEPT [0:0]
:FORWARD ACCEPT [0:0]
:OUTPUT ACCEPT [767:109441]
-A INPUT -m state --state RELATED,ESTABLISHED -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p icmp -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -i lo -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p tcp -m state --state NEW -m tcp --dport 22 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 162 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 514 -j ACCEPT
-A INPUT -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
-A FORWARD -j REJECT --reject-with icmp-host-prohibited
COMMIT
```

The line

```
-A INPUT -p udp -m state --state NEW -m udp --dport 162 -j ACCEPT
```

doesn't work as expected. I mean UDP traffic to port 162 is not matched by the rule and still being dropped with icmp-host-prohibited sent back.

Could you please advise how I should modify the config to allow UDP traffic to port 162?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your prerouting table is modifying the inbound port and that happens before INPUT. Update your INPUT rule to match the prerouting port, 1162.